# How to set default publish action in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When publishing my asp app from VSCode I am using command

```
dotnet publish -c release -o Z:\inetpub\wwwroot\Tools
```

Is there a way to make this the default publish command, so I don't need to type it into the terminal each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set this up as [a VS Code task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Something like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "publish",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "dotnet publish",
            "args": [
                "-c", "release",
                "-o", "Z:\inetpub\wwwroot\Tools"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried adding task args as a single string (e.g. "-c Release"). This results in the error: MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.